# JQuery addClass on click

Tags: jquery, onclick, addclass

I am trying to add class using JQuery to a button when it is clicked. The following codes show my class and JQuery onclick event with its handler:

CSS

```
.input-highlight {
     background-color: #1E90FF;
     color: white;
}
```

JS

```
$("#elv-geo").on("click", hightlight);

function hightlight() {

    var georgian = $("#geo-elv");

    georgian.addClass("input-highlight");

}
```

When I had "visibility: hidden" in the class, it did work, but with the above code, it doesn't. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Amit what would that change?

Comment: @Amit is there any benefit to wrapping `highlight` in an anonymous function instead of passing it directly?

Comment: @JanDvorak is right! no need for a defined fucntion.

Answer (score 1):

You used once  `$("#geo-elv")` and the other time `$("#elv-geo")`. This may cause your problem..

Also, you should consider using the following syntax:

```
$("#geo-elv").on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('input-highlight');
})
```

Comment: So what's the problem, he used one click ID and another for change class ID.

Comment: Didn't you read? "I am trying to add class using JQuery to a button when **it is clicked**"

Comment: Yotam, I did confuse id-s and although the class is added to that button when clicked (seen in browser inspect element), it doesn't do what the class says (change background color etc.). I tried using $(this) too, but no success.

Comment: Your css might be overridden by some other rules.. try `background-color: #1E90FF !important;` or changing the location of the rule in the page for it to work. also try to use the rule with the selector: `#geo-elv.input-highlight` which is more specific thus gets higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

```
.input-highlight {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    color: white;
}

var id = "#elv-geo"; // is it elv-geo or geo-elv?
$(id).on("click", highlight);

function highlight() {
    $(id).addClass("input-highlight");
}
```